# Concrete5: how do i find the controller functions from the url?

Tags: php, function, concrete5

I am new to `concrete5`.

I want to edit the email template which is sent to the customer email id in the forgot password section.

Where do I find the controller function, if the url is www.mydomain.com/login/password_sent/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard email content is taken from proformas in /concrete/mail/. In your case, from /concrete/mail/forgot_password.php.

Rather than edit the actual file, you should create an override by copying it up to /mail/forgot_password.php and editing the file there.

The concrete5 core will then use the override copy of the file instead of the core file.

Comment: can you tell me from which controller, the variables like($uName, SITE, $uName, $changePassURL) are being passed ?